# Add in System.out::print , i am not able to understand it

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, system.out

```
map.values().stream().distinct().forEach(System.out::print);
```

I am not able to add comma in the above code for adding a comma between the values of the hashtable

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly then you want to store all the values of the map into a comma separated string so You can use String.join(",",list);

The second argument above is the list of strings which is your map values

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // An example map
        Map<Integer, String> map = Map.of(1, "One", 2, "Two", 3, "Three");

        // Join the values using comma as the delimiter
        String values = map.values().stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.joining(","));

        // Print
        System.out.println(values);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Three,Two,One
```